# Dynamic languages for embedded devices?

Tags: ruby, dynamic-languages, embedded-linux

I need to deploy a dynamic language to a small embedded Linux device, and have difficulty finding the right one: I want to build a small web-application with this language (with a small framework like Sinatra or Camping ) and write some scripts for maintenance.

I would prefer Ruby, as I have some experience in it, but after several days of trying to cross-compile it, I could only build the barebone interpreter, without the libs (miniruby). The problem with it is, that it's just Too Damn Large: more than 1 MB stripped!

What language are you using, and how difficult was it to get it working?

Comment: See this question for several related options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082751/what-are-the-available-interactive-languages-that-run-in-tiny-memory

Answer (score 5):

I don't use it personally but [lua](http://www.lua.org/) has a very small footprint.

Comment: a co-worker of mine has had great success with lua.  Depending upon your needs it can get pretty small as well.

Comment: I'll second this.  Lua is quite easy to get going since it will pretty much compile as ANSI C89 (as either C or C++).

Feel free to check out eLua, which also has some patches and modules that make it suitable for microcontroller environments: http://www.eluaproject.net/  (the whole project might not meet your needs, but some of the ideas/patches/code might be useful)

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic languages are very, very hard to minify. Perhaps [tinypy](http://www.tinypy.org/) will give you some inspiration for squeezing out more.

Answer (score 1):

I am investigating this myself, and I have found some interesting candidates:

- [eLua](http://www.eluaproject.net/) - An implementation of Lua specifically for embedded devices.
- [p14p](http://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip/) - Python on a chip.
- [Forth](http://www.forth.org/) - Good old Forth, what more can I say?

Comment: Just a small update: since then I have successfully compiled & used Ruby, with mixed results: it is fully functional, and it made my life easier implementing the webservice, but on the other side it is fairly slow, and somewhat a memory hog.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ruby 1.8.7 on a Techbase NPE GPRS modem. It has a 180MHz ARM processor, and has a lot of services already on it (eg Apache, embedded PostgreSQL). Works fairly well, but you need to be aware of a few issues with ruby on it (eg Timeout can cause ruby to SegFault).

Planning to move up to ruby1.9 later in the year...